# fontspec/xelatex: Font not found after upgrade from TeXLive 2019 to TeXLive 2020

Tags: fontspec, texlive-2020

I have just upgraded to TeXLive 2020, downloaded by torrent.

A file that compiled without error and which gave the expected PDF throws up an error now. My  MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
% Compiles with xelatex under TeXLive 2019 but not under TeXLive 2020.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
% From https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/amadeus
\newfontfamily\amadeus{Amadeus Regular}
% From https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/kingthings-calligraphica
\newfontfamily\kingthings{Kingthings Calligraphica Light}
\begin{document}
Test.
{\amadeus\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Test\normalfont}
Test.

Test.
{\kingthings\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Test\normalfont}
Test.
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
(/home/chandra/extra/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `Kingthings Calligraphica Light', contains ' '

! Package fontspec Error: The font "Kingthings Calligraphica Light" cannot be
(fontspec)                found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
```

I have attached an image of the PDF when compiled with TeXlive 2019.

[image]

Kindly suggest what to do to make it work under TeXLive 2020.

**P.S. Where are the fonts installed?**

```
fc-list | grep Amadeus
```

gives

```
/usr/local/share/fonts/a/Amadeus.ttf: Amadeus Regular,Amadeus:style=Amadeus Regular,Regular
```

Likewise

```
fc-list | grep Kingthings
```

gives

```
/usr/local/share/fonts/k/Kingthings_Calligraphica_Light.ttf: Kingthings Calligraphica Light:style=Light
/usr/local/share/fonts/k/Kingthings_Calligraphica_2.ttf: Kingthings Calligraphica 2:style=Regular
/usr/local/share/fonts/k/Kingthings_Calligraphica_Italic.ttf: Kingthings Calligraphica Italic:style=Calligraphica
```

**Paths to TeXLive 2019 and TeXLive 2020**

Path to TeXLive 2019: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH;`

Path to TeXLive 2020: `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH;`

*Note*:  The TeXLive trees live under `/home/chandra/texlive` which is symlinked to `/usr/local/texlive`.

**Invocations to xelatex**

```
source texlive2020
which xelatex
```

gives

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex
```

wehereas

```
source texlive2019
which xelatex
```

gives

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex
```

The executable files `texlive2020` and `texlive2019` contain the lines

```
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/20xx/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH;
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/20xx/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH;
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/20xx/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH;
```

where `xx` is `20` and `19` respectively.

The invocations to the two different versions of `xelatex` are accomplished so:

`xelatex` from 2020: `source texlive2020; xelatex [filename]`

`xelatex` from 2019: `source texlive2019; xelatex [filename]`

**Log files from TeXLive 2019 and TeXLive 2020**

[xelatex log file from TeXLive 2019.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g43po70ig73xrys/TSE-upgrade-error-texlive2019.log?dl=0)

[xelatex log file from TeXLive 2020.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/91fhfrqqxa26b3j/TSE-upgrade-error-texlive2020.log?dl=0)

**Font-related**

1. `fc-cache -fsv` and `luaotfload-tool --update --force` successfully executed.
2. lualatex [filename] *compiles successfully* with the above source file to give the correct PDF output. No problem there.
3. `Kingthings Calligraphica Light Light` does not work.
4. If the font is specified as
   `\newfontfamily\kingthings[Path=/usr/local/share/fonts/k/]{Kingthings_Calligraphica_Light.ttf}`
   *both* `xelatex` and `lualatex` *compile successfully*.
5. `fontforge` detects a non-compliant PostScript font name for `Kingthings Calligraphica Light`. I will communicate this to the font author.

**Conclusions**

The workaround is to invoke the font by filename and path. This works for both `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

There is still the issue of identifying what has changed between TeXLive 2019 and TeXLive 2020 to make a non-compliant font name fail. I will leave this to the experts.

For now, it seems prudent to use filename and path for fonts reported as "not found".

Thanks to @Davislor for suggesting this workaround through his comments.

Comment: The Kingthings Calligraphica font work well on my side (macOS with xelatex/lualatex). How about checking or just (re)installing that font to your operation system? On Windows, an administrator permission may be required.

Comment: Thanks, @muzimuzhi Z. I did that and find that there is no change. Moreover, while it works with TeXLive 2019 (and its fontspec) it does not with TeXLive 2020. So, I suspect some change in fontspec could hold theclue.

Comment: where did you install the font?  is it in the 2019 path but not the 2020 one?

Comment: @David Carlisle: I have augmented my question to add this information.

Comment: The path in your error message says, texlive 2020 were installed under /home ! Are there two different texlive installations, maybe?

Comment: @Keks Dose: ```/usr/local/texlive``` is symlinked to ```/home/chandra/texlive``` and the 2019 and 2020 trees both live there. There is only one TeXLive 2019 tree living side by side with one TeXLive 2020 tree. No duplicate installations.

Comment: Maybe someone can find the error, if you provide (1) the way you call xelatex (a) 2020 and (b) 2019 and (2) if you provide the respective logfiles. However, those installations of two different systems with a symlink to your ~/ sounds weird.

Comment: I will list the invocations to ```xelatex``` and try to provide the logfiles by editing the question. The TeXLive files reside in a directory writeable by me in ```$HOME``` and the symlink in ```/usr/local``` is done using ```sudo```. I believe that this is recommended. In any case, I have been following this method for >10 years now and have had no problems until now.

Comment: Try running `texhash` after `source texlive2019`?

Comment: I just did that and the 2020 gives me the same error as reported while 2019 compiles without murmur. Alas!

Comment: Does the filename `Kingthings_Calligraphica_Light.ttf` work?

Comment: You might try rebuilding the font caches with `fc-cache -fsv` and `luaotfload-tool --update --force`. Although `fc-list` is finding it correctly.

Comment: Since the name of the font is `Kingthings Calligraphica Light` and the style is `Light`, it might also be expecting the face `Kingthings Calligraphica Light Light`.

Comment: @Davislor: Thank you for directing attention to the font/font file. I have reported in full under "Font-related" above in my question. I will communicate with the font author too.